# What equivalent zoom level would ISS astronauts would be seeing the Earth?

Tags: zoom, satellite

Like for Google Maps, there are 20 zoom levels. What zoom level would approximately give us the view that astronauts have?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know for google map but if you use Google Earth (desktop version) the altitude is in the bottom right corner. As the space station altitude is a little more than 400km (or 250 miles) you could try to zoom to the right altitude and have the same view as the astronauts

Comment: Great!! Google Earth web version have this feature as well. Though Google Maps had moved to globe view, it doesn't have the feature yet.